# Изменение background одного элемента при смене темы приложения

Tags: android

В активити моего приложения есть список событий, состоящий из тасков. Таски разделены между собой сепаратором, представленным в виде RelativeLayout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:text="Separator"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:id="@+id/tvSeparatorName"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Я реализовала смену тем в приложении. Возникла трудность при изменении цвета сепаратора - в светлой теме от должен быть одного оттенка, в темной - другого.

```
 <color name="backgroundSeparatorLight">#e4f062</color>
    <color name="backgroundSeparator">#e16d07</color>




 <resources>
    <style name="AppThemeLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryLight</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkLight</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentLight</item>
        <item name="background">@color/backgroundSeparatorLight</item>
    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="background">@color/backgroundSeparator</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Как правильно прописать background сепаратора? Буду благодарна за помощь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Необходимо в файле **attr** задать свой кастомный атрибут, который будет отвечать за цвет. Например атрибут будет следующий:

```
<attr name="separator_color" format="color"/>
```

Затем ты указываешь значение этого атрибута в своих темах:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppThemeLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryLight</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkLight</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentLight</item>
    <item name="separator_color">@color/backgroundSeparatorLight</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="separator_color">@color/backgroundSeparator</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Теперь ты можешь засеттить необходимый цвет в зависимости от темы. Важный момент - указать где этот цвет использовать. Пример:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:text="Separator"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="?separator_color"
    android:id="@+id/tvSeparatorName"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

где атрибут **android:textColor="?separator_color"** подставиться из твоей темы.